# The type CucumberOptions is deprecated how can i resolve the issue

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;  : After importing error message The type When is depreciated .This occur for all the annotataion & in Test Runner file its shows"The type CucumberOptions is deprecated".
```

I have installed Java 12 with POM

```
cucumber-java :4.7.2
cucumber-junit: 5.5.1
junit:4.12
```

version
Any suggestion to resolve the query..

Comment: Did you read the java doc?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of
 `import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;`

Use this `import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;`

And `@CucumberOptions( monochrome = true,plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" })`